# Ubuntu on WSL and apt cache

Tags: apt, package-management, apt-cacher-ng

I have several Ubuntu servers, VMs and laptops on my home and office network. I have them all using apt cache for updates (saves a lot of bandwidth)

I know I can't use this cache with anything but x86_64, so the ARM SOCs update on their own. But can I also update Ubuntu on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) from the same cache? It's x86_64 as well, so wouldn't the Kernel update when WSL updates (or perhaps when Ubuntu on WSL updates via the store) but the rest of the packages would update from the same cache? Or are all the packages different for that version of Ubuntu?

Comment: It's important to note that Ubuntu on WSL is not the same as Ubuntu elsewhere.  WSL is really [only intended to allow Windows users to use Bash](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#can-i-run-all-linux-apps-in-wsl) and Linux command line utilities.  You should look at this FAQ topic: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#why-are-there-so-many-errors-when-i-run-apt-get-upgrade

Comment: Thank you for that link!
I am using just a few additional CLI items, installed from the default repositories, so I guess from that FAQ, I don't think much risk experimenting then. I just didn't want to cause any issues elsehwere.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else stumbles upon this.
The WSL Linux kernel is not the same as a standard Ubuntu one, but some of those non-kernel packages were updating from the cache.

Not a huge size saving, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my one WSL (1) environment, `/etc/apt/sources.list` lists entirely normal Ubuntu package locations/servers.  I think it should be happy using a shared apt cache.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I don't have much additional installed (only a few items from the standard repositories) so I guess worth an experiment then, and if I end up killing it, then lesson learnt and not too hard to reinstall :)